# Removing items in one 2d numpy array from another

Tags: numpy, list-comprehension

I have a function, `foo`, which returns an np array containing every possible combination of `np.arange(n)` when `k` numbers are removed.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations 

def foo(n,k):
    return np.array([np.delete(np.arange(n),i) for i in combinations(range(n),k)])
```

The output of this function is correct, but the list comprehension it uses means a longer processing time when larger numbers are involved. Is there a more efficient solution to this using pure numpy?

I have tried using `np.delete` with `idx` as the key (a 2d array that contains the values to remove on each row), along with a broadcasted `np.arange` without success:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

k = 2
n = 15

idx = np.array([i for i in combinations(range(n),k)])
arr = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(n), (idx.shape[0],n))

res = np.delete(arr, idx, axis=1)
```

This code produces an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there a more efficient solution to this using pure numpy?"* . **No**.

itertools is efficient. Instead of deleting k elements, choose (n-k) elements.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain, combinations

def foo_new(n,k):
    return list(combinations(np.arange(n),n-k))

def foo_old(n,k): ## your function
    return np.array([np.delete(np.arange(n),i) for i in combinations(range(n),k)])

# In [5]: %timeit foo_new(25,5)
# 3.77 ms ± 62.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# In [6]: %timeit foo_old(25,5)
# 151 ms ± 676 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```